# Angular without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code that is using JQuery i would like to use only Angular. And i don't know how i can do it. Thanks

```
var startProduct = $("#product-overview").position().top - 60;
            var endProduct = $("#global-features").position().top + 150;

            $(document).scroll(function () {

                var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                if ($routeParams.section) {
                    $("#product-submenu").show();
                } else if (y > startProduct) {
                    $("#product-submenu").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $("#product-submenu").hide();
                }

                if (y > endProduct) {
                    $("#product-submenu").css("opacity", "0");
                } else {
                    $("#product-submenu").css("opacity", "1");
                }

            });
```

Comment: do refer this [jQLite api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The $ is just a shortcut for a lot of things; for instance `$("#product-submenu")` is the short form of `document.getElementById("product-submenu")`.

You will also, in the case of the `.css` functions, need to use `document.getElementById("product-submenu").style.opacity = "1"` to update CSS rather than the accessor functions jQuery provides.

For `.show()` and `.hide()` you can use `document.getElementById("product-submenu")` followed by `.style.display="block"` and `.style.display="none"` respectively.

As for `.fadeIn()` this would require a bit more work, and might depend on your application how you want to implement it. If you would like fancy effects like `fadeIn` you might just want to include jQuery in the first place, but if this is the only one you need you can write a javascript function to change the opacity of the element. If the fadein effect isn't necessary, you can use `display="block"` as above and while it will not fade, it will show the element.

Comment: It could be argued $ is a closer shortcut to document.querySelectorAll as they both search based on CSS selectors.

Comment: ah! in the dark days before jQuery I never used that one much, and did everything by getElementById, but that makes sense and I am now wiser for it, thank you :)